# lxml xpath child vs xpath descendant

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I've got this snippet:

```
<div>
    <p>This content is flagged as <code>TODO</code>. It has another element of <code>TODO</code> neither of the nested elements should be a child of div.</p>
</div>
```

in lxml I'm using the xpath selection of:

`//div/child::*` This is giving me a list of three items p, code, and code. However, code and code shouldn't be considered children of div, but descendants of div. In fact, when I use `//div/descendant::*` I get the same three items. Ultimately I don't know how many children will be in a div, could be 1 or 100, but I only need the direct child, not any descendant elements.

Anyone have any ideas of how to do this with lxml? Or is it simply a bug I'll have to wait to get fixed?

Comment: Isn't `//div/child::*` exactly equivalent to `//div/*`? In any case, with lxml 4.9.2 and your sample data, `//div/child::*` returns only a single result, `[<Element p at 0x7f22f1ed4b80>]`. If you're seeing different behavior, could you update your question to include a complete [mcve]?

Comment: Interestingly I'm not seeing this in the large dataset. I've found a workaround, but something isn't right somewhere (could very well be in how my looping is occurring in the larger dataset). Thanks for confirming this however!

Comment: So, I finally figured this one out. I'm sure there's documentation that says don't do this... but I had an if statement that was ```if mycode.xpath('.//div/child::*'):``` ... it was that statement failing. That is, lxml if I assigned a variable to that same xpath gave me exactly what I wanted and I could then check to see if it contained something, just not short cut around it. Again, thanks everybody. I just wanted to follow up in case anybody else falls into this trap.

Answer (score 0):

`lxml` returns a single element `p` which however contains the `code` elements

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> doc = html.parse('tmp.html')
>>> doc.xpath('//div/child::*')
[<Element p at 0x7efcc04d8e08>]
>>> doc.xpath('//div/child::*')[0].xpath('//code')
[<Element code at 0x7efcc04ea318>, <Element code at 0x7efcc04fbc28>]
```

For `//div/descendant::*` it returns 3 nodes as it should

```
>>> doc.xpath('//div/descendant::*')
[<Element p at 0x7efcc04d8e08>, <Element code at 0x7efcc04ea318>, <Element code at 0x7efcc04fbc28>]
```